# Undefined variable PDO Connection

Tags: php, pdo

I have a separate file that contains the PDO connections i need.

this is the setConnection File.

```
$Poll = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=polls", "root", "", );
```

i'm trying to use this connection inside a class in other file, so i included it.

```
include_once "setConnections.php";
.
.
.
$Poll->query("....");
```

I'm getting "Undefined variable at line 12 ($Poll->....).

I have it defined in setConnections, what i'm doing wrong?

More code to help.

```
include_once "setConnections.php";
class question{
    private $id_poll;
    private $title;
    public function __construct($title, $id_poll){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->id_poll = $id_poll;
    }
    public function insere(){
        the message is saying the error is here $Poll->prepare("INSERT INTO perguntas (id_poll, pergunta) VALUES (?,?)");
        $a->bindParams(1, $this->id_poll);
        $a->bindParams(2, $this->title);
        $insert = $a->execute();
        if($insert >0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough surrounding code for context, but almost certainly you either defined `$Poll` inside a function and are trying to use it in a different one, or defined `$Poll` at global scope but are trying to use it inside a function.

Comment: If you post more of the surrounding code at both the time you call `new PDO()` and when you later use `$Poll`, we can help you sort out the probable variable scoping issues.

Comment: More code is in the question. I think my mistake is someting related with variable scope.

Comment: What about the code in `setConnections.php`? Is `$Poll` defined globally in that file, or inside a function?  To begin with, `$Poll` must be passed to `insere()` as a parameter. it is not in scope otherwise. It could also be passed to the constructor and stored as a property of the `question` class.

Comment: No, Poll is stored globaly in the setConnection, nothing else there. Whats the best way to create an "universal" file to store all my connections and dont have to pass $Poll as a parameter everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the PDO object `$Poll` at global scope inside `setConnections.php`, but it is not in scope anywhere inside your `question` class.  You will need to place `$Poll` in scope either by passing it as a parameter to functions that use it, or by setting it as a property of the `question` class objects.  I would use the property method, passing it to the constructor. This is known as *dependency injection*.

```
include_once "setConnections.php";

class question{
    private $id_poll;
    private $title;
    // Add a new property for the PDO object
    private $connection;

    // Pass it to the constructor
    public function __construct($title, $id_poll, $connection){
        // Set the property
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->id_poll = $id_poll;
    }
    public function insere(){
        // Now use the connection property inside the class.
        $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO perguntas (id_poll, pergunta) VALUES (?,?)");
        $a->bindParams(1, $this->id_poll);
        $a->bindParams(2, $this->title);
        $insert = $a->execute();
        if($insert >0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The other method would be to pass it explicitly to the `insere()` method:

```
    public function insere($connection){
        // Now use the connection property inside the class.
        $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO perguntas (id_poll, pergunta)VALUES (?,?)"); 
        // etc...
    }
```

In the comments you mentioned storing the connection "universally". That is achievable [using the `global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) inside your classes, in a constructor for example, but not recommended.

```
// This is not recommended.
public function __construct() {
  global $Poll;
  $this->connection = $Poll;
}
```

Instead, it is better to pass the connection once to the constructor and access it as a property inside your classes.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was a scope problem but i didnt know how to fix it. Now you give me a better vision of it.

Comment: My webserver might have a problem. I did what u said.  
    $pdoVar = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=polls", "root", "");
    $Pergs = new question($perguntas, $poll, $pdoVar);

and i keep having the same issue: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\Poll\classes\perguntas.php on line 20

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Poll\classes\perguntas.php on line 20

Comment: @MatheusSilva I can't say without seeing your current code, but `undefined variable $connection` suggests you may have used `$connection` inside the class instead of `$this->connection`.  Oh, I see my error above - I omitted `$this` inside `insere()`. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you, and i didn't see it too..my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error handling mechanism when you create new instance of `PDO`?

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=polls", "root", "", );
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If something goes wrong, you will see the message and will know what the problem is.

Comment: If not, the PDOException would be fatal anyway and halt before the subsequent code

Comment: No problems and no erros, nothing on the screen